# Windows privileges, getting handle of .dll when not admin, not sure

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, privileges, dll-injection

Ok, I'm learning about the Windows API and how to create threads/processes and get debug rights etc.  Very new so I apologize if this is a stupid problem.

Anyways, I'm creating a .dll injector to play around with, and have successfully been able to inject 32 and 64 bit processes, including explorer.exe by injecting my .dll file.  However, I'm trying to test this in a standard user mode and am having problems figuring out how.

Right now I'm compiling as x64 for both the .dll and injector.exe.  I'm trying to inject into a x64 process, primarily explorer.exe (which works on admin).  Using Visual Studio 2012, with some optimizations, no manifest, no debug(only when needed). 
OS= Win 7 x64

Also, I have tried to access the .dll from multiple places, E:\ drive is just another partition on my HD.

1. Why exactly does this happen?
2. What are some ways to get around it?  (References, explanations, examples wanted if possible)

The NtCreateThreadEx(); call returns a thread that is 0.  Thus it did not load correctly.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

#define CREATE_THREAD_ACCESS (PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ) 

using namespace std;

DWORD getPid(string procName);
int privileges();

typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING {
    USHORT Length;
    USHORT MaximumLength;
    PWSTR  Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING;
typedef UNICODE_STRING *PUNICODE_STRING;

typedef struct _OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {
    ULONG Length;
    HANDLE RootDirectory;
    PUNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    ULONG Attributes;
    PVOID SecurityDescriptor;
    PVOID SecurityQualityOfService;
} OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES;
typedef OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES *POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES;

typedef DWORD(WINAPI *NTCREATETHREADEX)
(
PHANDLE ThreadHandle,
ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
HANDLE ProcessHandle,
LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
LPVOID lpParameter,
BOOL CreateSuspended,
DWORD dwStackSize,
DWORD dw1,
DWORD dw2,
LPVOID Unknown
);

int main()
{
    cout << sizeof(void*) << endl;
    privileges();  //don't mind of the result, because maybe it fails because you already have that privilege

    DWORD pid = getPid("explorer.exe");
    if (pid == 0) return 1; //error

    HANDLE p;
    p = OpenProcess(CREATE_THREAD_ACCESS, false, pid);
    if (p == NULL) return 1; //error

    char * dll = "E:\\logger_mailer.dll";
    BOOL is32 = FALSE;
    BOOL fnWow64Ret = IsWow64Process(p, &is32);

    if (!fnWow64Ret)
    {
        cout<<"Error!!!!!!"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //if (is32)  //If true process is 32 bit
    //  dll = "D:\\logger_mailer.dll";
    //else
    //{
    //  dll = "D:\\logger_mailer.dll";
    //  //cout<<"Error"<<endl;
    //}

    unsigned long LoadLib = (unsigned long)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

    LPVOID DataAddress = VirtualAllocEx(p, NULL, strlen(dll) + 1, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    WriteProcessMemory(p, DataAddress, dll, strlen(dll), NULL);

    HANDLE thread;
    NTCREATETHREADEX NtCreateThreadEx = (NTCREATETHREADEX)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "NtCreateThreadEx");
    if (NtCreateThreadEx) {
        NtCreateThreadEx(&thread, GENERIC_ALL, NULL, p, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLib, DataAddress, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else {
        thread = CreateRemoteThread(p, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLib, DataAddress, NULL, NULL);
    }

    if (thread != 0){
        //injection completed
        WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);   //this waits untill thread thread has finished
        VirtualFree(dll, 0, MEM_RELEASE); //free myFunc memory
        VirtualFree(DataAddress, 0, MEM_RELEASE); //free data memory
        CloseHandle(thread);
        CloseHandle(p);  //don't wait for the thread to finish, just close the handle to the process
        cout << "Injection completed!" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Error!" << endl;
    }


    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

DWORD getPid(string procName){
    HANDLE hsnap;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pt;
    hsnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    pt.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    do{
        if (!strcmp(pt.szExeFile, procName.c_str())){
            DWORD pid = pt.th32ProcessID;
            CloseHandle(hsnap);
            return pid;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hsnap, &pt));
    CloseHandle(hsnap);
    return 0;
}

int privileges(){
    HANDLE Token;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &Token))
    {
        LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &tp.Privileges[0].Luid);
        tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
        if (AdjustTokenPrivileges(Token, 0, &tp, sizeof(tp), NULL, NULL) == 0){
            return 1; //FAIL
        }
        else{
            return 0; //SUCCESS
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

EDIT:  So, after David and Harry basically coddled me through stuff, I have found that it is my .dll code that is failing.  Also, my use of NtCreateThreadEx() was unneeded as CreateRemoteThread() does indeed work on win 7 x64.  Many, posts here on SO and other sites specify otherwise.  A simple message box was displayed to verify.

What is weird is that NtCreateThreadEx() works in admin mode, but not in standard.

Comment: Sounds like the compiler has optimised that code out.

Comment: Yes but why? Because I'm not allowed to access it?

Comment: It is just the assignment of a pointer local var. Compiler doesn't need the var.

Comment: "skips over" is not a very helpful description.  What exactly happens?  The value of `dll` is not set?  What do you think this has to do with access rights?

Comment: Give me a min and I will Edit the post with more of a description.

Comment: Anyway what is your question? Do you want to understand the behaviour of the debugger

Comment: I thought it was obvious.  I'm trying to figure out what is happening.  Yes, when I debug this code, I cannot see what values char *dll is.  Not only that but it skips over the code in the debugging process.  Like, I can place breakpoint on it and it never hits even though control flows right through it.  Also, looking at this disassembly it seems that the char * dll never makes it into the code (unless I'm reading this wrong, which I might be.)

Comment: The ultimate question is why will this injection work in admin and not standard user.  Again, I can post the code if someone wants to look at it.

Comment: You are reading it wrong. If you want help you should ask the real question and not give us false trails and needless asm.

Comment: I thought I was explicit.  How am I reading it wrong?  I'm not trying to give you false anything, just understand.

Comment: Because `dll` always has the same value, a constant string literal, there's no need for it to be a variable.  The compiler will just insert the string literal wherever `dll` is referenced.  That's got nothing to do with your actual problem, you've just gotten confused because you're running the debugger on a release build.

Comment: To diagnose the actual problem, the main thing you need to do is to add error checking so that you know which API call is failing, and what the error code is.  With that information we may be able to help.

Comment: My advice is to remove the asm, remove all the talk about debugger, and ask about why your injector fails. Start with some error checking.

Comment: Updated.  The problem is NtCreateThreadEx(); is an undocumented function in the winapi.  I can't find much of anything on it.  I also can't find out what the value of char * dll is.  In admin in debugging I can find exactly what the value of it is, regardless of it being a string literal or not.

Comment: Now there is no code! Note that you are not copying the null terminator. The `WriteProcessMemory` needs to be passed `strlen(...)+1`. You do need to check for errors. Why would you call `NtCreateThreadEx`. Call `CreateRemoteThread` like the rest of us do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Man, the code is in the link I specified...  In windows 7, CreateRemoteThread() will not work when calling from a different Session than the process injecting into.  Thus, only NtCreateThreadEx() seems to work.  Notice that CreateRemoteThread() is in there, and has been tried.  NtCreateThreadEx() works when I run as admin.

Comment: Please keep the code in the question. We don't really like off site links. I edited it back. Sorry to be fussy. We will get there.

Comment: Running with CreateRemoteThread() returns a value of 0xB8.  However, the injection does not complete as explorer.exe runs in Session 0 (I think).

Comment: explorer.exe does not run in a different session. But it might not want you to inject into it.

Comment: Does it work if your code has admin privilege but explorer.exe does not?

Comment: My injector and .dll work correctly in admin, but in standard mode it does not seem to inject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the following problems:

1. In the call to `WriteProcessMemory` you pass the wrong length. You need to pass `strlen(...)+1` in order to write the null-terminator.
2. There is no need to use the undocumented `NtCreateThreadEx`. Using `CreateRemoteThread` works perfectly well for injection.
3. You have only checked for errors on some of the API calls. You need to check errors on all your API calls. If you don't do that, nobody can know whether or not they succeed.

For what it is worth, I've never had to use `AdjustTokenPrivileges` to inject. I believe that you can skip that step.

---

In a comment you state that you are injecting into a different session. And you find that you need `NtCreateThreadEx` rather than `CreateRemoteThread`, and that injection only works when elevated. Of course, the requirement to inject into a process in a different session is pretty important. That should be included in the question rather than appearing in comments.

However, you should not be remotely surprised that you need to elevate to inject into a process in a different session. And for that scenario then quite possibly adding `SE_DEBUG_NAME` is needed.

In short, it seems to me that the system is telling you to run elevated in order to inject into a process in a different session. That seems quite reasonable.

---

On the other hand, you also state in comments that `CreateRemoteThread` returns a non-zero value. Which indicates success. That seems to say that you are mis-diagnosing the problem. If `CreateRemoteThread` is succeeding then the remote thread will run. You next need to work out what fails after that.

And you also say that you are trying to inject into the `explorer` process which does not run in session 0. So there is a lot of confusion here. Perhaps I jumped the gun in adding this answer.

In any case, in order for you to proceed I recommend:

1. Fix the call to `WriteProcessMemory`.
2. Work out which session the target process is in.
3. Add error checking.

Comment: I have corrected WriteProcessMemory() to account for strlen(...) + 1.  I have mashed around with the code to see what is happeneing, sorry for lack of checking.  With correcting WriteProcessMemory() and using CreateRemoteThread().  I am still returning 0xB8 from CreateRemoteThread() and while this should denote a successful creation, the .dll never executes.

Comment: How do you know that the DLL never executes?

Comment: I should say that the code is not executing in the way I expect it too.  I have tried to inject another process.  The process went from 13,204 kb to 13,228 kb...which is sufficient to say that the code was injected into the process.  However, the results of this give me no indication of a successful exection.  I both display data to the screen and email my gmail account with the dll.

Comment: Use Process Explorer to confirm that your DLL is being loaded. You have to understand that from our perspective we have to doubt all the information that you provide! It sounds to me that the remote thread starts. What happens next, who knows. That doesn't seem to be part of the question.

Comment: So what would cause a remotethread to run correctly in admin mode and not in standard?  Privilege? I will have to look into setting the SE_DEBUG_NAME.  Asking about Privilege was part of the original question...

Comment: Don't know. I've no idea what your DLL is doing. I'm not terribly keen on debugging this all the way to the end if you know what I mean. Does the DLL load into the explorer process?

Comment: I understand.  I just downloaded it.  I'm not sure what I need to see besides the process usage and memory statistics rising.  The dll is around 15kb and sends my gmail account an email of the last 500 characters typed from the keyboard using rudimentary GetAsyncKeyState().  I also can show a message box saying "Hello".  Neither of those happen in standard user, but work in admin.  Edit:If you want to see it I will post it.

Comment: In the View menu in Process explorer enable "Show Lower Pane". Then select View | Lower Pane View | DLLs. Then select explorer.exe in the tree view. Then look for your DLL in the lower pane.

Comment: No, my .dll is not listed there.

Comment: Is it possible that ASLR is biting you? Is it possible that kernel32 has a different base address in the explorer process from your process. In other words the thread proc that you pass is invalid.

Comment: It's possible.  But knowing that in admin everything works, I can't think of why as a standard user it wouldn't.  I'm just not knowledgeable enough.  Also, AdjustTokenPrivileges() returns 0, so wouldn't that mean that the privilege was there and was enabled?         Edit: Actually that is incorrect, it returns 0 on failure, but I'm accounting for that in a roundabout way.

Comment: That means the call failed and you need to call `GetLastError` to find out why.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51163/discussion-between-user2079828-and-david-heffernan)